# Content-length mismatch with Express when serving two files at the same time

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express

System details:

- Ubuntu 14.04 running on a Vagrant machine with VirtualBox;
- Node v5.4.1 and NPM 3.3.12 are currently installed;
- Using *forever* to keep the node server alive;
- Backend uses NodeJS with Express, MongoDB as database
- Frontend uses AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap

As software engineer, I decided my current (Wordpress) website is a bit of a disgrace, so I decided to try out creating my own fullstack website.

However, I am running into an issue I cannot explain, because either my JavaScript loads, or my CSS loads, but never both.

I have already tried different NodeJS versions, but to no avail. Regardless of version, the browser (almost) always fails to download either of the files as the content-length is mismatched.

The browser I use is the latest stable version of Opera, which is essentially the same as Chrome these days, except for the user interface.

What am I doing wrong?

Excerpts from [GitHub](https://github.com/StephanBijzitter/Skelware.com/tree/stackoverflow)

Working `index.html`:

```
<script src="/files/js/skelware.min.js"></script>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/files/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
```

Working `index.html`:

```
<!--<script src="/files/js/skelware.min.js"></script>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/files/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

*Not* working `index.html`:

```
<script src="/files/js/skelware.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/files/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

function connectDatabase() {
    console.log('Connection to Mongoose...');
    mongoose.connection.once('open', startApp);
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/skelware');
}

function startApp() {
    console.log('Connected to Mongoose at localhost:27017/skelware !');
    console.log('Starting application...');

    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    app.use('/cv', require('./api/cv/router'));
    app.use('/users', require('./api/users/router'));
    app.use('/files', require('./api/files/router'));
    app.use('/projects', require('./api/projects/router'));

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
    });

    app.listen(8080, function() {
        console.log('Started application at localhost:8080 !');
    });
}

connectDatabase();
```

files/router.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

var root = path.join(__dirname, '../../public');

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    var file = root + req.url;

    res.sendFile(file, function(err) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Vagrant provision file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Updating existing packages..."
sudo apt-get update -y || exit 1

echo "Installing build-essential..."
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential || exit 1

echo "Installing libssl-dev..."
sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev || exit 1

echo "Installing libkrb5-dev..."
sudo apt-get install -y libkrb5-dev || exit 1

echo "Installing MongoDB..."
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb || exit 1

echo "Installing NodeJS..."
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash - || exit 1
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs || exit 1

echo "Entering SuperUser mode..."
sudo su || exit 1

echo "Installing global NodeJS packages..."
npm install forever grunt-cli node-gyp -g --silent || exit 1

echo "Installing local NodeJS packages..."
cd /vagrant || exit 1
    rm -rf node_modules || exit 1
    npm install --silent || exit 1
cd .. || exit 1

echo "Compiling source files using Grunt..."
cd /vagrant || exit 1
    grunt build || exit 1
cd .. || exit 1

echo "Provisioning MongoDB server..."
mkdir -p /data/db || exit 1
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db || exit 1

echo "Starting MongoDB server..."
mongod --quiet --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log || exit 1

echo "Starting NodeJS server..."
cd /vagrant || exit 1
    forever start server.js || exit 1
cd .. || exit 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using express.static middleware for static content as described http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html here

Comment: Wow, I tried to create something that already existed. And indeed, the existing solution does work correctly, while mine doesn't. Thanks for the pull request, too!